# How do I add options to the ipv4 packet?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ip

I'm developing a network tool in C that will allow me to send custom packets to the host. It's good so far but I decided to implement the IPv4 options but I didn't find anything on how to do that.

I found the `struct options` but I don't know how to implement it with the `struct iphdr`:

```
struct options {
__u32       faddr;              /* Saved first hop address */
unsigned char   optlen;
unsigned char srr;
unsigned char rr;
unsigned char ts;
unsigned char is_setbyuser:1,           /* Set by setsockopt?           */
            is_data:1,          /* Options in __data, rather than skb   */
            is_strictroute:1,       /* Strict source route          */
            srr_is_hit:1,           /* Packet destination addr was our one  */
            is_changed:1,           /* IP checksum more not valid       */  
            rr_needaddr:1,          /* Need to record addr of outgoing dev  */
            ts_needtime:1,          /* Need to record timestamp     */
            ts_needaddr:1;          /* Need to record addr of outgoing dev  */
 unsigned char __pad1;
 unsigned char __pad2;
 unsigned char __pad3;
 unsigned char __data[0];
 };
```

Comment: Have you tried reading RFC 791? It shows how the IP header is constructed, including options.

Comment: Use `setsockopt()` with either `IP_HDRINCL` or `IP_OPTIONS`

Comment: "Package" meaning "packet" here?

Comment: From what I read, Socket Opt does not allow specifying options for the datagram itself. socket only

Comment: You read that where? That's not what it says in the *man* page: "IP_OPTIONS (since Linux 2.0): Set or get the IP options to be sent with every packet from this socket." And how many times are you going to re-post this question? Third time already by my count. Please stop that, and *edit* your question to improve it.

Comment: @user207421: That would indeed not be very good at having different options on each datagram.  But `IP_HDRINCL` covers that scenario.

Comment: [I am from Brazil and dont speak english. I am using Google translater ]            I had the idea of ​​creating a struct with all the members of the struct iphdr but I will add a new member at the end of the struc which will be the char options [40] member. Then I will add the bits that form the options as shown in RFC 791. I hope it works.